# AgGrid in Python giving blank grid

Tags: python, pandas, ag-grid, justpy

AgGrid in Python giving blank grid when run with Justpy to display a Dataframe on the webpage.

Please find below the python code I am trying to run... It is giving a blank grid can you please help me debug???

```
import pandas as pd

import justpy as jp

w1=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])

def grid_test():

    print(w1)

    wp = jp.WebPage()

    jp.Strong(text=str(w1), a=wp)

    grid = jp.AgGrid(a=wp)

    grid.load_pandas_frame(w1)

    return wp

jp.justpy(grid_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the example described in https://justpy.io/grids_tutorial/pandas/ work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue.  The issue for me resolved when I made certain the recordset contained no null values.  My orignal recordset had some null values.

Comment: see https://github.com/elimintz/justpy/issues/384